# I am trying to use assertNotSame but when I run the Junit test, it fails where it shouldn't

Tags: java, testing, junit, assert

I am currently creating a program designed to take pictures from flickr and put them up on a new window. I am making a Junit test to test whether any of the photos are the same. When I run the test, it fails, despite the fact I have ensured that the photos are all unique.

The code is as follows:

```
 public void test1() {
        PhotoViewer viewer = this;
        PhotoFinder finder = new FlickrPhotoFinder("***************************");
        PhotoController controller = new PhotoController3(finder, viewer);  
        viewer.setController(controller);
        controller.initialize();

        for ( int i = 0 ; i<20 ; i++ ) {
            for ( int j  = 0 ; j<20 ; j++ ) {
                if ( j != i ) {
                    assertNotSame(photoArray[i], photoArray[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The array photoArray contains photos in the form of JPEGs. There are 3 different searches which are used in the program as topics. photoController3 sets atleast one of the 20 spaces in photoArray[] to be of each the topics and then randomly allocates the remaining photos. In photoController3, the array is intialised such that photoArray[x] is the xth photo on flickr of that search, so no 2 photos can be the same.

Comment: Since we have no clue what's actually in `photoArray` it's difficult to provide much meaningful input.

Comment: We need to see the code that fills up the `photoArray` array